# android dialog phonegap

Tags: android-widget, cordova

I'm using phonegap on android. Now I encouter some problems about showing dialog on current activity.   There are two activity in my application(another is googlemap activity). The question is that, when my googlemap activity is in the top, but when I use phonegap show dialog method, the dialog is invisiable except you finish googlemap activity and return back to droidgap activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you specify the googlemap activity as the context when you create your dialog.